# Error creating function in DB2 with params

Tags: sql, db2, sql-function

I have a problem with a function in db2

The function finds a record, and returns a number according to whether the first and second recorded by a user

The query within the function is this

```
 SELECT
 CASE 
 WHEN NUM IN (1,2) THEN 5
 ELSE 2.58
 END AS VAL 
 FROM (
 select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS NUM ,s.POLLIFE  
 from LQD943DTA.CAQRTRML8 c 
 INNER JOIN LSMODXTA.SCSRET s ON c.MCCNTR = s.POLLIFE 
 WHERE s.NOEMP = ( SELECT NOEMP FROM LSMODDTA.LOLLM04 WHERE POLLIFE = '0010111003')
 ) AS T WHERE POLLIFE = '0010111003'
```

And works perfect

I create the function with this code

```
CREATE FUNCTION LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL(POL CHAR)
RETURNS DECIMAL(7,2)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC

 READS SQL DATA
RETURN (

 SELECT
 CASE 
 WHEN NUM IN (1,2) THEN 5
 ELSE 2.58
 END AS VAL 
 FROM (
 select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS NUM ,s.POLLIFE  
 from LQD943DTA.CAQRTRML8 c 
 INNER JOIN LSMODXTA.SCSRET s ON c.MCCNTR = s.POLLIFE 
 WHERE s.NOEMP = ( SELECT NOEMP FROM LSMODDTA.LOLLM04 WHERE POLLIFE = POL)
 ) AS T WHERE POLLIFE = POL
)
```

The command runs executed properly

> WARNING: 17:55:40  [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.439 secs] Command processed.
>   No rows were affected

When I want execute the query a get a error

```
SELECT LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL('0010111003') FROM DATAS.DUMMY -- dummy has only one row
```

I get

> [Error Code: -204, SQL State: 42704]  [SQL0204] BNOWPAPOL in LIBWEB
>   type *N not found.

**I detect, when I remove the parameter the function works fine!**

With this code

```
CREATE FUNCTION LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL()
RETURNS DECIMAL(7,2)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC

 READS SQL DATA
RETURN (

 SELECT
 CASE 
 WHEN NUM IN (1,2) THEN 5
 ELSE 2.58
 END AS VAL 
 FROM (
 select  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS NUM ,s.POLLIFE  
 from LQD943DTA.CAQRTRML8 c 
 INNER JOIN LSMODXTA.SCSRET s ON c.MCCNTR = s.POLLIFE 
 WHERE s.NOEMP = ( SELECT NOEMP FROM LSMODDTA.LOLLM04 WHERE POLLIFE = '0010111003')
 ) AS T WHERE POLLIFE = '0010111003'
)
```

**Why??**

Comment: The problem is might be in how you _call_ the function, not in the function itself.

Comment: Note that you were defining the function IN parm as CHAR, but you're calling with a VARCHAR parm. The signature shouldn't match. It's not clear, however, why the parm removal worked. I wouldn't have expected that unless maybe VARCHAR is a default.

Comment: When you don't specify the character parameter length, 1 byte is assumed, so `POL CHAR` is equivalent to `POL CHAR(1)`. I'm assuming when you call the function as `BNOWPAPOL('0010111003')` the system is looking for a function with a different signature.

Comment: @mustaccio io tried BNOWPAPOL('0') but error persist

Comment: @user2338816 change VARCHAR instead CHAR is the correct answer, but `CREATE FUNCTION LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL(POL VARCHAR)` is not valid, `CREATE FUNCTION LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL(POL VARCHAR(10))` is the correct param, please change the comment to answer to mark it, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement:

```
SELECT LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL('0010111003') FROM DATAS.DUMMY
```

causes this error:

> [Error Code: -204, SQL State: 42704] [SQL0204] BNOWPAPOL in LIBWEB
>   type *N not found.

The parm value passed into the BNOWPAPOL() function is supplied as a quoted string with no definition (no CAST). The SELECT statement assumes that it's a VARCHAR value since different length strings might be given at any time and passes it to the server as a VARCHAR.

The original function definition says:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LIBWEB.BNOWPAPOL(POL CHAR)
```

The function signature is generated for a single-byte CHAR. (Function definitions can be overloaded to handle different inputs, and signatures are used to differentiate between function versions.)

Since a VARCHAR was passed from the client and only a CHAR function version was found by the server, the returned error fits. Changing the function definition or CASTing to a matching type can solve this kind of problem. (Note that a CHAR(1) parm could only correctly handle a single-character input if a value is CAST.)